# AngularJs: Highlight the whole div card with color after clicking and deselect after another card is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
         <li ng-repeat="item in shoppingItems" class="list-group-item text-center clearfix">
          <div class="card-body text-dark" ng-click="highlight(item.id)">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">{{item.itemName}}</span>
            <img ng-src="{{ item.imgUrl }}" width="40" height="40"/>
            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>


 $scope.highlight = function(id){
        console.log("Card id"+id);
        document.getElementById('selectedRow').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
```

Note: I can get the card id after I select on the card. But when I click on the card the color doesnt change.

Comment: Using DOM api to manipulate is really not a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ng-class to dynamically adding the class:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-bxpwnw?file=home%2Fhome.controller.js

JS:

```
$scope.highlight = function(itm) {
  itm.highlighted = true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li ng-repeat="item in shoppingItems" class="list-group-item text-center clearfix">
          <div class="card-body text-dark" ng-click="highlight(item)" ng-class="{'color--highlighted': item.highlighted}">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">{{item.itemName}}</span>
            <img ng-src="{{ item.imgUrl }}" width="40" height="40"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.color--highlighted {
  background-color: blue;
}
```